# Различия методов Find(), FirstOrDefault() при использовании с Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, c#-faq

Если нужно получить запись из базы данных по ее первичному ключу, можно воспользоваться и тем и другим методом. Оба метода вернут объект сущности, если запись присутствует в базе, в противном случае вернут `null`.

В чем их разница и когда какой метод использовать?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Для поиска и получения объекта сущности можно воспользоваться методами:

`Find()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`.

**Рассмотрим каждый:**

- Метод `Find()` принимает в качестве параметра первичный ключ записи.

  Его особенность состоит в том, что в отличие от остальных методов, он сначала обращается к памяти и ищет запись среди объектов контекста, отслеживаемых EntityFramework'ом, и только потом (если ничего не нашел) выполняет запрос к бд. Если в контексте найдется объект, который еще не сохранен в базе, метод `Find()` все равно вернет его (с состоянием `Added`). Если запись не будет найдена ни там ни там, вернет `null`.

  Генерируемый SQL запрос:

  ```
  SELECT TOP (2) 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
  FROM [dbo].[Topics] AS [Extent1]
  WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p0
  ```

  Стоит обратить внимание, что в выборку попадает не одна запись, а две `SELECT TOP (2)`. Это используется внутренними механизмами EF для проверки уникальности записи. Если в результате окажется более одной записи с одним и тем же первичным ключем, EF сгенерирует исключение:

  > System.InvalidOperationException: "Последовательность содержит более одного элемента"
- Метод `FirstOrDefault()` принимает в качестве параметра предикат, что дает возможность искать не только по первичному ключу, но и по любому составленному условию.

  Например, найдем запись, у которой `Title == "test"`:

  ```
  var topic = context.Topics.FirstOrDefault(topic => topic.Title == "test");
  ```

  `FirstOrDefault()` в отличии от `Find()` каждый раз выполняет запрос к базе, не зависимо от того есть ли данные в контексте. Если из базы придет запись, отличающаяся от той что лежит в контексте, EF вернет запись из контекста. Если записи не окажется в базе, вернет `null`, даже если она есть в контексте.

  Генерируемый SQL запрос:

  ```
  SELECT TOP (1) 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
  FROM [dbo].[Topics] AS [Extent1]
  WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
  ```

  Тут ищет только одну запись `SELECT TOP (1)`. Если окажется что записей несколько, вернет первую.
- Метод `First()` аналогичен `FirstOrDefault()` с одним отличием - если запись не найдена, будет сгенерировано исключение:

  > System.InvalidOperationException: "Последовательность не содержит элементов"
- Метод `SingleOrDefault()` аналогичен `FirstOrDefault()` и возвращает объект сущности, либо `null`. Однако запрос генерирует подобный методу `Find()`:

  ```
  SELECT TOP (2) 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
  FROM [dbo].[Topics] AS [Extent1]
  WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
  ```

  И при обнаружении более одной записи выкидывает исключение:

  > System.InvalidOperationException: "Последовательность содержит более одного элемента"
- Метод `Single()` аналогичен `SingleOrDefault()` и отличается тем, что если запись не найдена, будет сгенерировано исключение:

  > System.InvalidOperationException: "Последовательность не содержит элементов"

---

**Подведем итоги:**

1. Когда использовать `Find()`?

   Когда искать нужно по первичному ключу и выбрать нужно все данные сущности. `Find()` не выполняет запрос, если запись уже загружена в контекст и, как следствие, будет превосходить в производительности все остальные методы. Однако если нужно выбрать какие-то определенные поля (например только `Id` и `Title`), придется воспользоваться остальными методами. То же касается и подгрузки зависимых данных (например через `Include()`) - `Find()` это сделать не даст.
2. Когда использовать остальные методы?

   Если нужна выборка определенных полей сущности или нужно также загрузить зависимые данные. Какие именно методы использовать зависит от индивидуальных требований: если вам нужно проверить существование записи (без генерации исключений), подойдут методы `*OrDefault()`:

   ```
   var topic = context.Topics
                      .Select(topic => new { topic.Id, topic.Title })
                      .FirstOrDefault(topic => topic.Id == 44);
   if (topic == null)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Если предполагается, что контекст может содержать локальные копии данных, можно получить их оттуда, не выполняя запроса к базе. Для этого нужно обратиться к свойству `Local` объекта `DbSet`:

   ```
   Var topic = context.Topics.Local.FirstOrDefault(topic => topic.Id == topicId)
            ?? context.Topics.FirstOrDefault(topic => topic.Id == topicId);
   ```

---

Используемые источники:

- [MSDN: Entity Framework Querying and Finding Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573936)
- [Primer on Selecting Data Using Entity Framework](http://judeokelly.com/primer-on-selecting-data-using-entity-framework)
- [StackOverflow: Are Find and Where().FirstOrDefault() equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720143)
- [StackOverflow: Using .Find() & .Include() on the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576283)

Comment: @PavelMayorov перепроверил, возвращает `null` даже если объект есть в кеше

Comment: Метод `Find()` принимает на входе целую коллекцию первичных ключей.

Comment: @user3172616 это не коллекция первичных ключей, а потенциально-составной первичный ключ

Answer (score 2):

Это не ответ на вопрос автора, а поправка к предыдущему ответу пользователя tretetex. Что касается

> Его особенность состоит в том, что в отличие от остальных методов, он сначала обращается к памяти и ищет запись среди объектов контекста, отслеживаемых EntityFramework'ом, и только потом (если ничего не нашел) выполняет запрос к бд. Если в контексте найдется объект, который еще не сохранен в базе, метод Find() все равно вернет его (с состоянием Added). Если запись не будет найдена ни там ни там, вернет null.

FirstOrDefault(), Find(), First() всегда пытаются найти объекты сперва в кэше контекста данных, а затем в БД если в кэше не нашли. (Прочитал в книге "C# 6 IN A NUTSHELL" Joseph Albahari & Ben Albahari стр 384 русского издания) Вот тесты которые я провел

```
        using (var context1 = new DataContext())
        {
            //В данный момент у грузовика из context1 Title = "Грузовик"
            var truck1 = context1.Trucks.FirstOrDefault();

            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                //У этого грузовика из context2 по прежнему Title = "Грузовик"
                var truck2 = context.Trucks.FirstOrDefault();

                truck1.Title = "Грузовик обновленный";

                context1.SaveChanges();

                //В данный момент у грузовика из context1 Title = "Грузовик 
                //обновленный"
                //этот цикл для задержки
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    var sum = Math.Sqrt(i);
                }

                //У этого грузовика из context2 по прежнему Title = "Грузовик", хотя в 
                //БД уже имеет Title = "Грузовик"
                var truck3 = context.Trucks.FirstOrDefault(t4 => t4.Id == truck2.Id);
            }
        }
```

Тесты это подтвердили